# Unable to test a celery chain when tasks are executed by different celery apps

Tags: python, django, testing, celery, django-celery

I have two celery apps in my environment that are :

```py
app1 = Celery('app1', broker=BROKER_URL1, backend=BROKER_URL1)
app2 = Celery('app2', broker=BROKER_URL2, backend=BROKER_URL2)
```

From a Django app within a `web` container I need to call a chain of tasks:

- `task1` is executed by `app1`
- `task2` is executed by `app2`

The two apps have different virtual environments / python versions so there no way of executing both tasks by the same `app`.

```py
@app1.task(bind=False)
def task1():
    return {"key": "value"}

@app2.task(bind=False)
def task2(result):
    return result["key"]

task_chain = (
    app1.signature('app1.task1') |
    app2.signature('app2.task2')
)
```

I am then trying to test the chain works correctly - task1 appears to execute correctly but task2 errors:

```py
@override_settings(CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)
def test_chain(self):
    task_chain.apply_async().get() # Error: celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'app2.task2'
```

How can i test this chain?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have same result backend to run a chain across multiple apps first. Even with same backend, both tasks will be run by worker associated with `app1`. Celery chain doesn't seem to follow the app associated with tasks while running. Check [this issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3350).